# Empty Default on Mysql int data type

Tags: mysql

Need help, first, i'm sorry if my english is very bad.
I have a task.

[image]

[image: ![enter image description here]

At total. The default must be empty not zero. But i have tried to type :
total int(5) not null default ''); but there is an error. 
"Invalid default value for 'total'".
Please help me to fix this. Thank you

Comment: Please dont use pictures. Instead, simply [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52913909/edit) the question to add code as text here.

Comment: For `int` datatype (it is a numeric datatype), value can always be a number only or `null`. If you dont want `0` as default value, set the default value as `null`

Comment: Sorry i'm newbie here. Thanks for your answer ^^

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get this error is, because you are trying to assign an empty string to an int field.

```
int = only allows values like 1,2,3,4,5,6...
char = allows multiple characters like 'ABDC' or ''
```

One way of fixing that would be to either change the datatype from Int to varchar or char like this:

```
create table seller (
    idseller char(3) not null default '',
    idproduct char(3) not null default '',
    total char(5) not null default ''
)
```

If you need that field as an int field you can also try to set "default 0".